# Is there is any method to create User defined data types in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, ddl

Is there any method to create **user defined data types in MySQL**.

Like:

```
create type Dollars as numeric (12,2) final 

create table department
(dept_name varchar (20),
building varchar (15),
budget Dollars);
```

**In MySQL**

Comment: No, there is no such feature in MySQL.

Comment: You can always upgrade to Postgres, where this can be achieved by using a `domain`